# "One of your chip's performance" or "One of your chips' performance"

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

What I mean to say is that you have several microchips, and I'm offering to boost the performance of one of them. In that case, is it correct to say ...?

> You can improve...
>
> 1. one of your chip's performance
> 2. one of your chips' performance

Option 1 seems right to me, because I'm talking about the performance of a single chip, but option 2 seems right to me also, because just within the "one of your chips," as in "one of your chips broke down" the *chips* are obviously plural.

I understand that I could sidestep the issue and say something like "the performance of one of your chips", but I am nevertheless curious which one of the above would be correct.

Comment: There _is_ a twist here. 'One of my friend's cars is in the garage' and 'One of my friends' cars is in the garage' include count usages ('One of my friend's three cars is in the garage' / 'One of my friends' three cars is in the garage').  **But** the noun involved after the set partitive _here_ is a non-count usage. It resists pluralisation, but it sounds wrong in the singular form. I can't see a way round this other than to rephrase using the periphrastic rather than the Saxon genitive.

Comment: My chip, your chip?? Who would say this, the computer tech guy?

Comment: Thanks. Through one of the suggested duplicate questions, I understood that it's 'one of your chip's performance' in my case, but I rephrased it anyway. @Lambie, I realise it sounds weird out of context, but it's in a video game where I think it works quite naturally.

Comment: Personally, I would say: The performance of one of your chips.

Comment: "chips" here is definitely plural, even though you are only talking about one of them. I disagree with the (unsourced) answer in the linked question.

Comment: @Lambie +1. And as for cars in the garage, is it necessary to communicate that you have more than one friend at the same time you say their car is in the garage? *My friend's car is in the garage.*

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that @_Lambie's comment reveals the correct approach: *chips* must be plural (giving the possessive form *chips'*), even though the non-countable quality of only one chip is being referred to. Interestingly, if it was a **countable** noun, eg *side*, "the side of one of your chips is damaged" describes a single side and multiple chips, whereas "one of your chip's sides is damaged" is referring to a single chip with multiple sides, one of which is being described. You're quite right that the *countability* of the noun makes all the difference!

Comment: To put it another way, it makes no sense to say "Look at this chip. One of its performance is sub-standard". Semantically, in "One of [XX possessive] performance", the term "one of" can only be used when referring to multiple items, and since *performance* here is uncountable, it must be the other term that is plural.

Comment: Since the **countability** of the item's quality or characteristic is a key factor in how to approach this kind of sentence, and countability is not addressed in either of the supposed duplicates, I'm voting to reopen the question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you don't seem to have read my comments, as I referred to the "non-countable **quality**" of the chip/s – **the *performance* being the specific non-countable quality here** (but it could have been *uniqueness*, *composition*, *silicon*, *compliance*, *heat*, etc). Because the specified quality is a non-count noun, the phrase "one of" (i.e. one of *several*) cannot refer to that quality so it **must** refer to *chips*. The possessive of *chips* is *chips'*. I repeat: **the non-countability of *performance* leaves no option but to use the plural possessive.**

Answer (score 0):

In "one of your chips" the word "chips" is plural, ending in "s". Therefore the apostrophe should come after the "s", so "one of your chips' performance" is correct. Putting the apostrophe before the "s" would be talking about the performance of one of your chip (no "s").

Comment: But at a claimed duplicate we find the accepted answer to 'My first though was "one of the families' [corrected] house", taking "one of the families" as a single noun and appending ' to it. This ... sounds ... a bit strange, though.':  'The construct you suggest is rather awkward as you said yourself. The best way to talk about the specific house is to rephrase the sentence and say instead: "...this will probably entail a party at the house of one of the families."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I concur about the best way to express the required meaning.

Comment: Remember the Master Rule. Orwell's Sixth. (Of course, it's admittedly highly subjective, and even if he were still alive, we'd all be arguing about whether his 'sounds outlandish' set is the correct one.)

Comment: This answer states that *one of your chip's* is wrong, then states (as if the earlier statement and the fact that *chips* is plural imply it) that *one of your chips'* is correct. It implicitly assumes that at least one of those forms is correct. This assumption is invalid.

Comment: @RosieF, I did not claim that *one of your chip's* was wrong until after I had claimed that *one of your chips'* was correct. When making the possessive form of a noun one appends either an apostrophe then "s", or merely an apostrophe. The apostrophe is not inserted into the word. If James has a car it is correct to write of it as *James' car*. However *Jame's car* would not belong to James, but to Jame.

Answer (score -1):

From how I see it, chip's is correct. If you are talking about a singular chip, then saying 's is correct. Multiple chips would move the s in front of the apostrophe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But at a claimed duplicate we find the accepted answer to 'My first though was "one of the families' [corrected] house", taking "one of the families" as a single noun and appending ' to it. This ... sounds ... a bit strange, though.': 'The construct you suggest is rather awkward as you said yourself. The best way to talk about the specific house is to rephrase the sentence and say instead: "...this will probably entail a party at the house of one of the families."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It should be "one of the families' houses" because there is more than one house to choose from. And yes, that could mean that at least one family had more than one house itself; but that doesn't actually matter, because there is still more than one house to choose from.